# Is it possible to upgrade PowerShell 5.0 to 5.1 on Windows 10 Pro version 1511?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, upgrade

Is it possible to upgrade PowerShell 5.0 to 5.1 on Windows 10 Pro Version 1511?

Windows 10 RTM and 1511 have PowerShell 5.0; there is 5.1 and PowerShell Core (a.k.a. 6.0).

PowerShell is installed with WMF installer however everywhere I search, it appears like Windows 10 RTM/1511 are stuck forever at 5.0.

Comment: I cannot see why this is a question for SO but would it be dangerous when you simply try it? I would predict that it will not hurt you.  ;-)

Comment: Olaf–PowerShell is a powerful programmer tool that can do many things we can do in .NET c# and other environments ... SO is a programmer forum and many programmers that i know use PowerShell so imho this is an appropriate venue for such a question–YMMV.  regardless, i would try it if i could find a WMF 5.1 installer the would work on this particular version of win10–Windows Update tells me my workstation is up to date yet PowerShell is still stuck at 5.0 ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion); my gut feeling is that the PowerShell Team has abandoned Windows 10 RTM/1511; installers i tried failed.

Comment: OK - first: as you can read here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) SO is about **code**. Your question is about system management. ;-)  Second: Do you have some  particular problems with PS 5.0 you wouldn't have with 5.1? If not - just stay on 5.0.

Comment: update your Windows 10 version to a newer version like 1709. 1511 left support for Home/Pro users. Only Enterprise/Education still get updates.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is, yes you can, that is by design, just like yo u can install PowerShell v6 on a target supported system, even one running other versions of PowerShell.

So, no, this is not a programming question but a PowerShell 5.1 operating systems requirement question.

The system requirements for every PowerShell version is in the PowerShell documentation.

> Windows PowerShell System Requirements
>
> This topic lists the system requirements for Windows PowerShell 3.0,
>   Windows PowerShell 4.0 and Windows PowerShell 5.0, and for special
>   features, such as Windows PowerShell Integrated Scripting Environment
>   (ISE), CIM commands, and workflows.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/windows-powershell-system-requirements?view=powershell-5.1

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the other answers I believe its not possible to upgrade Windows PowerShell independent of the operating system version on Windows 10 specifically. While there is a separate installer for Windows Management Framework 5.1 (so that you can upgrade PowerShell independent of the OS on other versions of Windows), you will see if you attempt to download it that they don't provide a Windows 10 compatible version of that installer. The [WMF 5.1 Operating System Compatibility page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.1/compatibility) indicates that WMF 5.0 and WMF 5.1 "Ships in-box", with the further note:

> About "Ships in-box*": The features of WMF 5.0 were included in the
>   original Windows 10 RTM version. The features of WMF 5.1 were included
>   in Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10 Anniversary Edition. WMF 5.1 is
>   not applicable for these operating system versions, as the updates are
>   provided via Windows Update.

As far as I know, the only valid way to install Windows PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 10 is to install the Anniversary Edition of Windows 10 (1607) or later.

Note that PowerShell Core (6.0) can be installed independently of the Windows version (and alongside Windows PowerShell) but PowerShell Core is a significantly different version of PowerShell (built on .NET core).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It's possible. Download WFM 5.1 and install it

To check the version use  -> $psversiontable